# Settings is no longer exists in TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-6

I used TinyMCE version 5.10.2.

I add toolbar dynamically in version 5.10.2.

```
var tinyMceInstance = tinymce.get('tinymceid');
tinyMceInstance.settings.plugins += ' image';
tinyMceInstance.settings.toolbar[4].items.push('image');
```

But when I upgrade tinyMCE version from 5 to 6, settings is not available.
How can I add toolbar dynamically in tinyMCE version 6.x ?

Comment: Looks like `settings` was removed in v6, and the replacement is to use commands, at least based on [their documentation](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/migration-from-5x/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI0JC4-fGQ_AIVVINaBR2MWwboEAAYASAAEgIaL_D_BwE#mceaddeditor-and-mcetoggleeditor).

Comment: And what is the command for add toolbar dynamically @PaulT.